# 1 Timothy 1:20; How did this happen in the days of the apostles?

Tags: eschatology, 1-timothy, satan

1 Timothy 1:20; DRB;

> 20 Of whom is Hymeneus and Alexander, whom I have delivered up to Satan, that they may learn not to blaspheme.

It seems that Paul has the authority to deliver the Blasphemous, and Sinners to Satan for discipline and punishment. This act Not to take place except when Jesus gets His authority in His Kingdom after the last days.

So, how did this happen in the days of the apostles?

Comment: Paul had no such authority to deliver anyone to Satan - he simply was advising to let him alon to allow the consequences of his sin to wreak its consequences on the sinner.

Comment: @Dottard It doesn't seem like that from Paul's words.

Comment: "This act Not to take place except when Jesus gets His authority in His Kingdom after the last days" - What are you referring to here?

Answer (score 1):

Discard the traditional teachings of men, in favor of God's word and it will make sense.  The scriptures define the "last days" as the end of the days of the Mosaic covenant, and the end of the days of that sacrificial temple in Jerusalem.  The apostles were living in "the last days".

> *"19 But with the precious blood of Christ, as of a lamb without blemish and without spot:  20 Who verily was foreordained before the foundation of the world, but was manifest in **these last times** for you,"* (1 Pet. 1:19-20, KJV)

> *"19 but with precious blood, as of a lamb unblemished and unspotted -- Christ's --
>
> 20 foreknown, indeed, before the foundation of the world, and manifested **in the last times** because of you,"* (1 Pet. 1:19-20, YLT)

> *"19 but with the precious blood of Christ, like that of a lamb without defect or blemish. 20 He was destined before the foundation of the world, but was revealed at **the end of the ages** for your sake."*  (1 Pet. 1:19-20, NRSV)

Peter told them that Christ had been manifested in "these last times," while he was speaking to them in the first century AD.  And, we know that Christ was manifested on earth in the 1st century AD.  Therefore, as a mathematical principal when A equals B, and B equals C, then A must also equal C.

Christ was manifested in the 1st century AD, and he was manifested in the last days, therefore the last days were in the 1st century AD.

The last days written in the scriptures were never speaking about the end of all time.  That is a false man-made doctrine.

See more scriptural proofs at:

It's Not The End of The World - Part I: What Does the Bible Really Say About These Last Days - [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/07/18/hello-world/)

It's Not The End of The World - Part II: Time Texts of The New Testament - [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/07/23/its-not-the-end-of-the-world-part-ii-time-texts-of-the-new-testament/)

Signs of Revelation - Part I: The Time of His Coming - [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/02/23/the-signs-of-revelation-part-i-the-time-of-his-coming/)

Daniel and The End Times - [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/05/09/daniel-and-the-end-times/)

The Signs of The Feasts - Part II: Christ Told His Disciples When He Would Return - [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/07/21/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-ii-christ-told-his-disciples-when-he-would-return/)

There are many more scriptural proofs to explore that the last days spoken of and prophesied in the Bible were always defined by God as the end of the Mosaic covenant, and the end of the national politic of the Jewish state.

Therefore, Paul was living in the last days, and he delivered up Hymeneus and Alexander to their own devices, their own desires and sins into the ways of the adversary.